Movie about an evil guy taking a kid to a cult to survive
It's an English movie. The entire thing is filmed in a weird, saturated filter. I had watched the movie on YouTube about two years ago, but it's since been taken down.
The movie is ultimately about a father that is fighting himself over whether it's not he should sacrifice his own kid so he can survive a car crash. He works in an office, spends more time working than he does with his family.

One of the first scenes is the kid getting taken by a guy in rags that uses a little drum to travel through portals, and there's a group of people trying to stop him, they break one of his drums, turns out it was the one he needed to get the kid to the cult he's supposed to take the kid to in order to get his life back.

The rest of the movie he is in a coma, and that's where the main character comes in. The movie follows his journey to getting the kid to the cult, the group trying to stop him get help from a blind guy, and at the end of the movie he gets to the cult, then you find out he's the father, and he ends up fighting them in order to save his kid.

The main character the movie follows has a long nose, wears black ragged clothing with a hood and has chains dragging from him.
The show is not animated, no actors that I could remember clearly.

The plot characters seem to exist in a parallel dream-like reality, walking and fighting among regular people without being seen.

There's a scene where the group plants a timed device in a multi story building and have to protect it from the cult, there's a fight scene in a hallway.
Another scene the main character has one of the group members chained up along with the kid, and they're walking along an overhead freeway, he's got the kid and woman behind him. He goes to an odd building where there's a seemingly witch that he requests a new drum from, and she demands payment in the form of the defender woman's hair. The blind man causes the main character's car to crash through a chain reaction of events that leads to him being hospitalized. 


Please see Identify-This-X Questions guide on how to write good identify this movie question. For example add better descriptive title, origin-country, colour, decade, language, plot details, actors etc. of the movie. I highly recommend doing that - otherwise it will be closed in day or two.

Ink (2009)

The film begins with a business man in a hurry to get into his car, he appears to be stressed and somewhat distraught. He gets in and starts down the city streets, screaming suddenly at the top of his lungs before a truck running a red light crashes into him. As he falls unconscious, he dreams of playing with his little girl Emma. At first he is stern and hesitant to play with her, but he gives in when she pretends to be taken away by monsters and runs to save her from them. The dream then fades to black.

Full synopsis
